# Scalings that can be used during QSAR

Tags: machine-learning, multiple-regression, qsar

Respected sir/ madam

When we perform QSAR say for some Biological activity prediction

For the features that is on the independent variables

Say in my case the independent variables are topological indices

Is normalization of the features permitted to get QSAR MLR model  equation

Answer (score 0):

In the typical use of of linear regression (ordinary least squares) normalization does not effect the results. Only the obtained regression coefficents will likely be larger as your normalized topological indices will have smaller values after the transformation.

In case you want to estimate the parameters of your linear regression with some other method it might important that you only use normalized input variables